# How do I prevent a textview from expanding but also prevent words being cut off?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

What I have so far

[image: Created UI]

I want to prevent the Location textview from expanding beyond a certain point. I have achieved that by using barriers in my constraintlayout. Now i want to prevent any words from being shown that are cutoff by this barrier(as you can see in the picture). Is there any way to achieve this?

It would be helpful for my usecase as i show closest geocoded location first(spicy jalapeno) so if the most general geocoded location(most likely country and postal code) is cut off it wouldn't matter...

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_home_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="126dp"
        android:text="Today's Date"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mass_attendance_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Mass Attendance"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Shift_home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Shift_home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mass_attendance_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView3"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="823dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.36" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.24" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="guideline5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="67dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="Date:"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/date_home_textview"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Set padding to the textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below attributes to TextView:

```
android:lines="2"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"  // or false
```

will append "..." at the end.

Comment: it works! would it be possible to somehow expand this ellipsis on user click?

Comment: You can use ExpandableTextView its is custom textview  easily available over net.